# Regular expression for specific part of url

Tags: regex

I'm learning to write regular expressions and am trying to get a specific part of a url. For example,

```
https://domain/#/customerName/profile/profileName/jobs/jobName
```

where "customerName" is a variable but "domain and "profile" are constants.

How would I obtain profileName given this string? I've come up with

```
^\/(?!https:\/\/domain\/#\/#\/*\/profile\/)
```

but don't really know how to cut off the rest of the string after "profileName"

Comment: You have two `#` in your regexp, but it's only once in the example URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`customerName` is a variable, but assuming it doesn't contain any slashes, you can match it with `[^\/]+` (which means "repeat any character but a forward slash") after the `/#/`. The same pattern works for `profileName`. So, you can use:

```
https:\/\/domain\/#\/[^\/]+\/profile\/([^\/]+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/aToq8N/3

The `profileName` will be in the first captured group.

Note that because the URL doesn't contain `/#/#/`, but just `/#/`, use `\/#\/` in the regular expression instead of `\/#\/#\/`.

Comment: is this different when domain contains specific characters? I tried my string on that website but it doesn't work. My domains are always of format "value.hyro.com". I'm also looking for "profileName" not "customerName"

Comment: Oops, thought you were looking for `customerName`, see edit

Comment: how do I filter out "." characters? My domain is always "value.hyro.com" and this regex fails, but your example works

Comment: @XinWenyu `.`s are special characters in regular expressions - a `.` means "match any character". For a literal period, escape it with `\.`

Answer (score 0):

Even if your domain is fixed, you may use this expression too fore the domain part

```
 [^\/]+
```

This way it can contain dot in addition to alphabetic characters,among other things.